# EF LINQ spatial query times out using Contains() method in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, spatial

I have a spatial query (SQL Server 2012) using LINQ (lambda syntax) that times out after approximately 30secs, and I cannot work out why. I have checked indexes, and run the Tuning Advisor but indexing all appears to be in order. I am just trying to get the polygon that contains a given 2D point.

```
    PointXY point = new PointXY(x, y);
    Parcel parcel = db.parcels.Where(p => p.Geom.Contains(point)).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have tried rearranging the query to using the `Within()` method, with the same result:

```
    Parcel parcel = db.parcels.Where(p => point.Within(p.Geom)).FirstOrDefault();
```

However, if I just request a count of the number of matching polygons, the (correct) result is returned immediately.

```
    int count = db.parcels.Where(p => point.Within(p.Geom)).Count();
```

I cannot work out how to resolve this, and wondering if there is something fundamentally wrong with my approach.

Comment: what does the generated SQL look like? Run the SQL Profiler and capture the SQL sent to the server.

Comment: Simplifying the query, it is as follows (takes 54 secs to complete): 
`SELECT TOP (1) [shape], [id]
    FROM [dbo].[parcels] 
    WHERE (@point.STWithin([shape])) = 1`
PS. @point declaration with changed coordinate...
`declare @point sys.geometry
set @point=convert(sys.geometry,0x9108EEEEE10C23DBF9FEDF6B3A41E3A59BE429B65541)`

Comment: and does the sql run and return the expected result?

Comment: Yes, after 54 seconds. I rebuilt the spatialindex, and the execution plan does not appear to be using the spatial index. Researching that now...

Comment: ...and deleting the spatial index confirms this. The same query takes 54 seconds with no spatial index.

Comment: Could you post structures of `Geom` and `Parcel` (or `Point`)? I think that manipulation of complex objects - and converting it like `@point=convert(sys.geometry,0x9108EEEEE10C23DBF9FEDF6B3A41E3A59BE429B65541)` can be main problem. Maybe yours query can be simiplified

Comment: Out of curiosity, were the bounds for bounding box for your spatial index such that it completely contained all of your parcels and your point simultaneously? Also, I'm just throwing darts here, but I typically write this sort of query with STIntersects, but it shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: I have tried STIntersects() with the same result. I also tried extending extents but all features are entirely within. The problem appears to be that the spatial index is not being used for my query. I found lots of references to this in SQL Server 2008 but not 2012. @michasm I have very little control over the generated query, as it is being generated from LINQ in my c# code. However, I tried setting `@point` manually via `Point(x,y,SRID)`, with the same result. The **bottom line** is the spatial index is not in the query execution plan, and the query takes the same time without any index.

Comment: @tr3v I know that you cannot modify autogenerated query :) but I think that you could simplify your linq query - to ommit complex types comparsion (because of their conversion on real SQL query level). As I wrote - can you post `PointXY`, `Geom` (if its a class also) and `Parcel` classes structures?

Comment: @michasm - I have corrected the code above (I was missing the geometry member). My declaration for `Geom` in point and parcel is `public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry Geom { get; set; }`

Comment: If I force the use of the spatial index `SELECT FROM .. WITH(INDEX([idx_spatial])) WHERE..` the response is immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **currently** cannot specify index hints with Entity Framework (EF6), so I could never force the use of a spatial index. Possibly there is a way to change my LINQ query to trick EF into using the spatial index, but I could not find a way. My solution was to bypass EF and use raw SQL via `SQLquery()`.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[parcels] WITH(INDEX([idx_spatial])) WHERE (GEOMETRY::Point(@x, @y, 2193).STWithin([shape])) = 1";
var args = new DbParameter[]
{ 
    new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "x", Value = point.XCoordinate }, 
    new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "y", Value = point.YCoordinate }, 
};

Parcel parcel = db.Database.SqlQuery<Parcel>(sql, args).FirstOrDefault();
```

I could not find a way to pass the `geometry` type as a parameter, so passed the x/y coordinates individually.